# I have defined 15 classes with name box1, box2, box3,...box15. How can I define the class without comma separation?

Tags: php, html, css

I have defined 15 classes with name box1, box2, box3,...box15. Style attributes are same for all the class. How can I define the class name without comma separation?
 
For Now, I have defined class as below,

```css
.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5, .box6, .box7, .box8, .box9, .box10, .box11,
.box12, .box13, .box14, .box15 {
     border: 2px solid black;
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
}
```

Later on I want to use this class to apply different hover style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
div[class^="box"], div[class*=" box"] {
    border: 2px solid black;
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
}
```

Basically you are trying to search for wild characters in css. You can check for more [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/css3-attribute-selectors/)

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer that exactly I want.